# What happened to leverage buyouts?

Tags: finance

Back in the 1980s leveraged buyouts were a common event. Financiers like T. Boone Pickens would borrow money, buy a controlling interest in a publicly traded stock and then re-engineer the company, for example, by selling it off in pieces.

This activity seems to be a thing of the past. I assume some law was passed to prevent leveraged buyouts. What was the cause of the demise of leveraged buyouts?

Comment: Half of your last [20 questions](http://economics.stackexchange.com/users/1448/lassie-fair?tab=questions&sort=newest) have been answered. Have you considered accepting any of the answers yet? So far (Sep.5th/16) no answers have been accepted.

Comment: Taking 5 minutes to Google "leveraged buyout" I have found a 2014 instance of a leveraged buyout and 2016 July plans to do more, so perhaps all is not as it "seems".

Comment: @denesp I know they still occur, but it seems that they occur much less frequently than in the 1980s.

Comment: "it seems" $\neq$ statitics

Comment: denesp ≠ spelling